# Why can't I access some tables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

I am running into some strange problem in PostgreSQL

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql Blogging
psql (10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

Blogging=# \dt
               List of relations
 Schema |         Name          | Type  | Owner 
--------+-----------------------+-------+-------
 public | Blogs                 | table | e
 public | Posts                 | table | e
 public | __EFMigrationsHistory | table | e
(3 rows)

Blogging=# select * from Blogs
Blogging-# ;
ERROR:  relation "blogs" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from Blogs
                      ^
```

The same problem occurs when I log in as the owner of the tables:

```
$ psql -U e Blogging
psql (10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

Blogging=# \dt
               List of relations
 Schema |         Name          | Type  | Owner 
--------+-----------------------+-------+-------
 public | Blogs                 | table | e
 public | Posts                 | table | e
 public | __EFMigrationsHistory | table | e
(3 rows)

Blogging=# select * from Blogs; 
ERROR:  relation "blogs" does not exist
```

I created the database when running my application which uses Entity Framework, following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli. But I had [some problem with the application,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59673778/how-to-avoid-null-value-in-column-violates-not-null-constraint-using-valuegen) not sure if they are related to my question here.

Comment: `"Blogs"` is a different name than `Blogs` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS - don't create your tables using double quotes: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Why didn't `\dt` show the table names containing double quotes? I create `"Blogs"`  by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli#create-the-database, and how did it add double quotes in the table name?

Comment: **You** (or the tools you are using) added the the quotes, Postgres doesn't do that on its own. If you run `create table Blogs (...)` it will be created in lowercase (as the link to the manual in my previous comment explains)

Comment: Why didn't \dt show the table names containing double quotes?

Comment: I can only guess, but maybe because the developers of `psql`thought it's obvious that quotes are needed. Other SQL clients might display that differently

Comment: I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli#create-the-database,   I still don't see how the double quotes in the table names were introduced.